# Singular meaning for "tombeaux"?

Tags: pluriel

Can "tombeaux" refer to a singular tomb? Like how the plural french word "recherches" refers can be translated as the singular english word "research"?

Comment: The noun *tombeau* is neither a mass noun (like *sable*) nor a [plurale tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) (like *lunettes*), so I'm not sure what's going on. Are you sure you don't mean the adjective *tombal* (as in *pierre tombales*), as jiliagre points out? It would be spelled *tombaux* in the plural, without an e.

Comment: I meant tombeaux. I wanted to know for sure. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

No, it can't. But the singular of "*tombeaux*" is "*tombeau*" (and not "*tombal*", which is an adjective). They sound the same, maybe that why you're confused.

For "research", it can translate to "*des recherches*", but that's when it's uncountable in English.

Answer (score 3):

The plural *tombeau**x*** can't be used to refer to a single tomb. Of course, the singular ***tombeau*** does.

**Research** is uncountable in modern English so almost never used in the plural<sup>1</sup>, while both ***recherche*** and ***tombeau*** can be used both in the singular and the plural.

While *tombeau* poses no problem, for *recherche* we have:

- ***La recherche*** which is similar to the English "research" when used generically, i.e. the research field/domain.
- ***Des/les recherches*** which represents a collection of distinct research activities, i.e. pieces of research. It is also usually translated to "research".

Even if there is a single piece of research, e.g. "my research about squaring the circle", we often prefer the plural:

- ***Mes recherches*** sur la quadrature du cercle is common
- *Ma recherche sur la quadrature du cercle* is rare

The singular would be used with:

- ***Mon étude*** sur la quadrature du cercle

<sup>1</sup> <sub>That wasn't the case until the 20th century. Earlier,
 ***researches*** [used to be prevalent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=researches%2Cresearch&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresearches%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresearch%3B%2Cc0).</sub>

Comment: Your first sentence was misleading, feel free to revert my edit if you dislike it.

Comment: @AnneAunyme I don't get how it could be misunderstood as it was clearly replying to the question. Answer re-edited to fully clarify the point anyway.